# Cannot Deploy Python Telegram Conversation Bot to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, telegram

I tried to deploy my python application to heroku but it shows application error how I could deploy my bot to heroku.
Here is what I did.

> Step 1:Run the code on Pycharm it works correctly.
>
> Step 2:Generate requirements.txt and Procfile.
>
> Step 3:Search Internet what to write inside Procfile.
>
> Step 4:After Ending All requirements file I upload the Whole Files to
> a GitHub repository.
>
> Step 5:Create an app in Heroku and Connected to My GitHub repository
> then Click Deploy Branch.

This is my Buildlog:

- -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
- -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
- -----> Python app detected
- -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
- -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
- -----> Installing SQLite3
- -----> Installing requirements with pip
- -----> Discovering process types
- Procfile declares types -> web
- -----> Compressing...
- Done: 74.8M
- -----> Launching...
- Released v17
- https://zsk766.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

This is my Code:
https://github.com/zieadshabkalieh/bla/blob/main/conversationbot.py

Where is my mistake..
Need Support.

Comment: What's in your Procfile? Have you tried running `heroku local` in the heroku cli to see the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with deploying the bot using GitHub I did everything but unfortunately, none of them worked :

so I tried to deploy it using GIT and Heroku CLI ...
the link below explains everything very simple and understandable, it worked for me ...

https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/anshumanfauzdar/telegram-bot-heroku-deploy